# Sending hash password to WebAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hash, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI application which is working fine. There are no problems loging, registering etc. However, I come across something which requires some attention. When somebody is registering or logging then their passwords are sent in plain text. I know we can apply HTTPS certificate and this will be solved. However, I am more looking for a solution where I can hash password and WebAPI can automatically pick it up. I am not looking to make changes to built in WebAPI functionality to hash and store PW. This is to also make sure that when I am using FF or Chrome developer tools then nobody can read the PW from data being sent.

I am using Angular or JQuery AJAX to make calls to my WebAPI.

Comment: Any two-way encryption can be undone and isn't very secure in the first place. You should really be using SSL for transmitting user account data.

Comment: Sending a hashed password doesn't do much good; the hash itself becomes the effective password.

Comment: If your attacker can use devtools on the client's page, you've already lost.

Comment: Thanks Guys...I totally understand the consequences of not using SSL. However, I was wondering, for e.g. if I am sitting next to someone and using dev tools to troubleshoot something, then that person can clearly see what my pw is as it is visible in request body. I was trying to avoid that in first place.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to encrypt the password in the frontend and send the hashed password and salt + rounds (when used) to the server.

Problem arises when the user tries to log in, you need to get the salt and roundings to the frontend, hash their password (which the typed in) send it to the server, there you do a compare like `hashedPassword == hashedPassword` and return true/false.

So in my opinion this is less secure than just doing all on the server side. Only benefit is, that no one can see your password in your dev-tools or in the payload.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I more looking for a way where I don't have to change built-in code for WebAPI for hashing and storing in DB. I tried couple of javascripts hashing methods like SHA1 and md5, which successfully hashed the pw, but it wasn't validated with WebAPI.

Comment: I assume you use ASP Identity 2.0 (or some other framework for user management). There, you have to set an option, where the password is not hashed on the server side (since it is already hashed). So this is just configuration, not overriding code.

Comment: Thanks @kadoga. I will take a look at that option. BTW, do I need to assign a SSL certificate to my WebAPI, or each user of my API needs to assign a certificate to their own site in order to send encrypted information (I am guessing latter).